# How do i pan on a image without changing its position?

Tags: premiere

So basically, im trying to create a meme using Adobe Premiere Pro 2020. I want to pan from one end of image to another, but without changing the image's position on the video.
I want it to look something like this:

Comment: Is it a still image -- a photo or image file, or a video clip?